# Sums of power of positive integers via binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing, integers, binomial-theorem

I have to prove this identity. I tried with induction and Newton's binomial, but I get stuck at some point. Could you tell me please what to do? [S(k, n) = 1^k + 2^k +...+ n^k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNPUE.png)  (you can see the identity by clicking on the sum, I'm sorry, I'm new to this site!)
$$S_k(n)=\sum _{m=1}^n m^k$$
$$1+\sum _{k=0}^{r-1} S_k(n) \binom{r}{k}=(n+1)^r$$

And after that I have to find the formula for S(1, n), S(2, n), S(3, n) and S(4, n).
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Write successively
\begin{align}
(n+1)^k&= n^k+\binom k1 n^{k-1}+\binom k2 n^{k-2}+\dots+\binom k{k-1}n+1 \\
n^k=(n-1+1)^k&= (n-1)^k+\binom k1 (n-1)^{k-1}+\binom k2(n-1)^{k-2}+\dots+\binom k{k-1}(n-1)+1 \\
\vdots \\
2^k=(1+1)^k&= 1^k+\binom k1 1^{k-1}+\binom k2 1^{k-2}+\dots+\binom k{k-1}1+1 ,
\end{align}
add all these equations and simplify.

Comment: Thank you so much!!